# Prestashop css issue on mobile and table devices

Tags: css, prestashop, background-color, mobile-devices

I am making an android app which basically when I run it, it accesses a URL where I am using the default prestashop theme. The issue is that I have changed the background colour and its fine when I access it from the URL. BUT when I am trying to access it from my android app the background colour is not changed. I guess I have to change the media CSS background colour on the global.css file but I am not sure. Anyone can give me some advice here ? Many thanks.

PS. Background colour was changed as followed here http://cart-help.com/topic/63-background-change-in-prestashop-16/

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a cache problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS probably is cached. You can solve this by adding a unique code to the url of the CSS, like:

```
/path/to/your/style.css?version=2
```

You can increment the version number on each request or specify a timestamp in there using testing and debugging. In production code, you should only change the version number if there is actually a new version of the CSS, that way, the CSS can be efficiently cached as long as you want, but you can always force a new version by changing the url.

Comment: Hello @GolezTrol Thank you for your reply I will try this out tomorrow and I will let you know if this was the solution on this particular case. Many thanks again.